# Issue with performance of SQL with 'group by' (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table as below (i'm using MySQl 5.6):

```
CREATE TABLE `sm_query_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_type_id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `clicks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `impressions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_uri` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And I need run below SQL:

```
SELECT
                *, SUM(clicks)total_click,
                SUM(impressions)total_impression,
                SUM(clicks)* 100 / SUM(impressions)ctr,
                AVG(position)position_avg
FROM
                `sm_query_1`
WHERE
                (
                 `search_date` >= '2015-10-01'
                AND `search_date` <= '2015-12-30'
                )
GROUP BY
                `keyword`
ORDER BY
                `total_click` DESC
```

When table 'sm_query_1' has 6 million records (in period: 2015-10-01 ~ 2015-12-30), this SQL need about 3-5 minutes to run.
I tried to creat indexes for column `search_date` and `keyword` but speed not be improved.

How to optimize this table structure and this SQL command?

(i want to this SQL run only <= 30s)

Comment: i cant see the create index in the Create table statement. please post yout indexe and a EXPLAIN of your SELECT

Answer (score 1):

I think you shuold use a composite index base on more selectible colum

eg try alternatively one of this and use the most performant

```
 CREATE INDEX my_index_name1
 ON `sm_query_1` ( `keyword`, `search_date` );
```

or

```
 CREATE INDEX my_index_name2
 ON `sm_query_1` ( `search_date` , `keyword`);
```

try also between

```
where    `search_date`  between  '2015-10-01' and  '2015-12-30'
```

instead of

```
where (
             `search_date` >= '2015-10-01'
            AND `search_date` <= '2015-12-30'
            )
```